# PhpStorm autocommit config files

Tags: git, phpstorm

PhpStorm is pushing changes to **master** without asking permission nor notifying me when this happen.

This happen even if I'm not on master, there is a merge commit but no new local branches are shown (git branch)

This happen each time I close the program.
The commits are named like this:

> PS-2016.1

Here is a list of the files:

```
_mac/hg.xml
other.xml
databaseSettings.xml
editor.xml
...
```

Mac OS X El Capitán
PhpStrom 2016.1
Git 2.8.1
Auth via ssh key

Comment: This must be caused by **Settings Repository plugin** -- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7566?pr=phpStorm -- possibly you have not configured it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Settings Repository plug-in solves this. (Is enabled by default)